# Should SVN repository include IDE project files?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have source files of project and then I create NetBeans project from this sources. Should I include this project in repository, or it's bad practice?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/q/347142/198011

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you store all sources that are required to perform a build. For example, in case of Visual Studio that includes "project" and "solution" files which enumerate all source files and store compilation/linking options. So I'm almost sure you need to put the NetBeans project file under source control.

Comment: In my case I have specific ant build scripts. And when I create NetBeans project it also define it's own build script that it use in debug and run. But maybe it can use project scripts? I'll go check docs

Comment: @Artyom: I guess you want those "debug and run" to be reproduceable - then you need stuff required for them under source control.

Answer (score 1):

There may not be a right answer for all situations. If you are the only one using this repository or are the only one using this subdirectory of the repository then there might not be a problem with storing the IDE project files. If lots of people are editing and building the same code, then it is probably best not to store the IDE project files.

In general, anything that is hard to create should be stored somewhere, either in a repo or on a webserver or something. Anything easy to create doesn't need to be stored.